# Fix unidentified characters in Solr

Tags: pdf, solr, tokenize, apache-tika, dataimporthandler

I've tried to import a PDF using  [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) with [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/). But part of result contains something like this:

> Be one
>   \nZLWK�RXU�QDWXUH��WDNH�\RXU�SLFN��HQGOHVV�PRXQWDLQV��LQȴQLWH�EHDFKHV��VSDUNOLQJ�FLWLHV��\nor
>   historical wonders

So I've tried to remove it using `ASCIIFoldingFilter` and `MappingCharFilterFactory` but it didn't work.

Anybody knows?

Comment: What does the original text look like? It is probably a charset issue.

Comment: Use the analysis page under Solr Admin to verify that your analysis chain actually works as you think it does. Most of those characters are valid ASCII characters as well, so they won't get removed or folded.

Comment: If you try PDFBox app (http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/apache/pdfbox/2.0.2/pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar)'s ExtractText on the file, you can see if the problem is with the processing of the file (highly likely).  If you have a problem there, open an issue with PDFBox or ask on the users list whether this is a bug in PDFBox or a broken PDF.